# Convert a varchar YYYYMMDD into datetime to compare with GETDATE()

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

What am I doing wrong here? I've looked through other posts but I'm getting different results than other people.

Trying to convert a varchar YYYYMMDD to datetime, and I keep getting:
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Attempts:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, EXPDATE)
CONVERT(DATETIME, EXPDATE, 102)
(CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(EXPDATE AS CHAR(8)), 112)) 
CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(expdate AS VARCHAR(8)))
```

Am I bungling something obvious here?

Comment: what is the date value?

Comment: Why not convert the other way to do the comparison?  GETDATE() can give you YYYY, MM, and DD, convert them to varchar, concatenate them and compare.

Answer (score 3):

You clearly have a values that are not valid dates.

In SQL Server 2012+, I would suggest `TRY_CONVERT()`:

```
TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, EXPDATE)
```

Then, look at the values that are `NULL` to see where data problems may be.

In earlier versions, you should be able to use `isdate()`:

```
(CASE WHEN ISDATE(EXPDATE) = 1 THEN CAST(EXPDATE AS DATE) END)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similarly formatted date field (DateKey) in a table I use.  I convert it to DATETIME using this syntax:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(DateKey AS VARCHAR(10)) AS DATETIME) FROM tblDate
```

Will this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Excellent. Gordon and chancrovsky, you helped me flush out the values that were formatted incorrectly. I used a version of what you posted and this worked

> (CASE WHEN ISDATE(ExpDate) = 1 THEN CAST(ExpDate AS DATE) ELSE NULL
>   END) as ExpDate

Thank you so much!